# Getting images variables from page to another

Tags: php, html, sql

Okay, I searched a lot and nothing helped me.
I have this form:

```
<form action="update.php" id="Form2" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="c">
  <div align="center">
    <?php echo "Updating information about Patient ".$row["name"]; ?>
    <table class="imagetable" border="1" cellspacing="3"  align="center">
      <th>Personal Informations</th>
      <th>Test Results</th>

      <tr><td>Name<br>
          <input type="text" class="large-fld" name="name" placeholder="Patient Name" value="<?php echo $row['name'];?>"/></td>
        <td>Remarcs:<br>
          <textarea type="text" cols="40" rows="5" class="large-fld"  name="remarcs" placeholder="Remarcs"><?php echo $row['remarcs'];?></textarea></td>
      <tr><td>Address<br>
          <input type="text" class="large-fld" name="address" placeholder="Address" value="<?php echo $row['address'];?>"/>
        </td>
        <td>Test<br>  <textarea type="text" cols="40" rows="5" class="large-fld"  name="test_res" placeholder="Test Result"><?php echo $row['test_res'];?></textarea></td></tr>
      </td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td>Phone Number<br>
          <input type="text" class="large-fld" name="phone_num" placeholder="Phone Number" value="<?php echo $row['phone_num'];?>"/>
        </td>
        <th>Files</th>
      </tr>
      <td>Scanned Echo Photo<br>
        <input type="file" class="" name="echo_photo" id="echo_photo" placeholder="Add echo photo" value="<?php echo $row['echo_photo'];?>"/></td>
      <td>Echo Files:<br>
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload"  value="<?php echo $row['echo_files'];?>"/><br></td>
      </tr></th></table>
    <div class="row" align="center">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="btnUploadId" class="large-btn" value="Update" onClick="btnOnClickUpload()">
      <input type="hidden" id="courseIdHidden" value="<?php echo $idd; ?>" /></td></tr>
      </table></div>
</form>
```

And i cant get the image and the file into next page to use them to update table using php:

```
$host=""; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name=""; // Database name 
$tbl_name=""; // Table name 


$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
if (isset ($_POST['name'])) {
  $name = $_POST['name'];
}
if (isset ($_POST['remarcs'])) {
  $remarcs = $_POST['remarcs'];
}
if (isset ($_POST['test_res'])) {
  $test_res = $_POST['test_res'];
}
if (isset ($_POST['address'])) {
  $address = $_POST['address'];
} 

if (isset ($_POST['phone_num'])) {
  $phone = $_POST['phone_num'];
} 
echo $name;
echo $remarcs;
echo $test_res;

echo $address;
echo $phone;
```

Echo of those variables are working great
How to complete this task ? Please help

Comment: Add the code you tried for file.

Comment: $uploaddir = "../../user_content/photo/";
$allowed_ext = array("jpeg", "jpg", "gif", "png");

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $file_temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];   
        $info = getimagesize($file_temp);
    } else {
        print "File not sent to server succesfully!";
        exit;
    }

Comment: There is a number of stray end tags in the html that may be causing your problems. For example the last `</table>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use $_SESSION variable to store information about your files, so that you will have access to them from different php files

Comment: what I need is getting values from html form, including texts and images, and update an sql table row with. I tried lots of codes online but nothing happens. So any help with codes ?

Comment: @droidnation you can save your files in some folder and save only path to them in your sql table, so when you want them back, you can just retrieve path and ( if it is an image) put it into your "src" attribute,